# What are the tab bar image sizes in XCode 5

Tags: ios

what are the requirements for Custom images on the tab bar of an iOS project?

Do the pictures need to be transparent at all?

Comment: It's all [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the documents for ios 7 UI guide.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html

Comment: Bout time someone answered